# Why does resizeColumnToContents work interactively at the python prompt, but not in a PyQt script?

Tags: pyqt

I've been working on a filebrowser application, and I'd like the first column (file name) to be resized properly on startup.  I can type the following code at the python prompt and the column resizes properly, but when I put it in a file and try to run it, the column is not resized.  Any idea why?

```
#!/bin/env python

import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
treeView = QTreeView()
fileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel(treeView)
rootDir = fileSystemModel.setRootPath(os.path.expanduser('~'))
treeView.setModel(fileSystemModel)
treeView.setRootIndex(rootDir)
treeView.setGeometry(100,100,1024,768)
treeView.show()
treeView.resizeColumnToContents(0)
app.exec_()
```

Of course, when I copy it to the python prompt, I leave off the app.exec_().  Is that what is causing the column to not resize?  (EDIT: I copied "app.exec_()" to the prompt and it did pretty much what you'd expect - the event loop started, and I was able to use the app, then close it, and then I was returned to the python prompt.)

Comment: BTW, I'm running RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.4 64 bit workstation, which includes Python 2.6.6 and Qt 4.6.2..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that replacing the call to `treeView.resizeColumnToContents(0)` with `treeView.header().setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)` results in the column being expanded when run from the Python prompt and from a script. I have no clue why `resizeColumnToContents` is not working as intended.

Side note: should `#!/bin/env python` be `#! /usr/bin/env python`? At least on my distro, `/bin/env` doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding.  Are you saying that you copy everything *except* the resizeColumn line and the column is properly sized on your system?

Comment: @DougWellington See my updated answer (I changed the function). Also, I would change `/bin/env` to `/usr/bin/env` since that seems to be the standard location (I've never seen `/bin/env` used). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env.